# MODIS 'system:time_start' format problem in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, time, format, datetime

In Google Earth Engine, what is the default format of time_start for MOD10A1 image?For example,

```
var modisCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
    .filterDate('2000-08-21', '2001-02-28')
print(modisCollection.first())

var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2000-04-28', '2001-02-28')
print(l5.first())
```

From the output, you can see that the MODIS `system:time_start` value of the image is 980985600000 and Landsat `system:time_start` value is 966866712747.

Are 980985600000 and 966866712747 in the same time format?
If the date from MODIS (980985600000) is not in UNIX time, how do I convert to UNIX time?

See a sample code [here](https://code.earthengine.google.com/3b326b1267efeacc81b8a4abbd241a6f)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's the number of milliseconds since the epoch (1 Jan 1970). You can convert it to an [`ee.Date` object](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.date) to use various date methods, including formatting for printing.

```
var modisCollection = ee.ImageCollection('MODIS/006/MOD10A1')
    .filterDate('2000-08-21', '2001-02-28')
print(ee.Date(modisCollection.first().get('system:time_start')).format("yyyy-MM-dd"))

var l5 = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR')
  .filterDate('2000-04-28', '2001-02-28')
print(ee.Date(l5.first().get('system:time_start')).format("yyyy-MM-dd"))
```